# show XML elemenst in HTML table with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

im novice in XML and XSLT. i have a an xml file ([book.xml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms762271%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

and i want to create HTMLtable with xsl transformation and show the details of books in that table.here is my xslt code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:template match="seite">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="document('book.xml')"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="catalog">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>
          <xsl:text>book</xsl:text>
        </title>
      </head>
      <body bgcolor="#ffffff">
        <h1>
          <xsl:text>Lieferungen</xsl:text>
        </h1>
        <hr/>
        <table border="1">
          <tr>
            <th>Nummer</th>
            <th>author</th>
            <th>titel</th>
            <th>genre</th>
          </tr>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </table>

        <hr/>
        <p>
          <xsl:text>Mit Webfehler: Wie vermeidet man die falsch sortieren Spalten?</xsl:text>
        </p>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="artikel">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
      </td>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="author|titel|genre">
    <td>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </td>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but i can't see the table in my browser.I see only the XML file.Would you please tell how can I do that correctly?
Thank' for your helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add the following line to your XML just after the first line:

   `<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="book.xsl"?>`

   And save if as `book.xml`
2. Edit your XSL file and save it as `book.xsl` in the same folder with your XML file

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
     <!-- You need a root xsl:template tag that matches the whole document -->
     <xsl:template match="/">
       <xsl:apply-templates/>
     </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="catalog">
       <html>
         <head>
           <title>
             <xsl:text>book</xsl:text>
           </title>
         </head>
         <body bgcolor="#ffffff">
           <h1>
             <xsl:text>Lieferungen</xsl:text>
           </h1>
           <hr/>
           <table border="1">
           <!-- I added thead and tbody just to make it prettier -->
             <thead>
               <tr>
                 <th>Nummer</th>
                 <th>author</th>
                 <th>titel</th>
                 <th>genre</th>
               </tr>
             </thead>
             <tbody>
               <xsl:apply-templates/>
             </tbody>
           </table>

           <hr/>
           <p>
             <xsl:text>Mit Webfehler: Wie vermeidet man die falsch sortieren Spalten?</xsl:text>
           </p>
         </body>
       </html>
     </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="book">
       <tr>
         <td>
           <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
         </td>
         <xsl:apply-templates/>
       </tr>
     </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="author|title|genre">
       <td>
         <xsl:apply-templates/>
       </td>
     </xsl:template>

     <!-- If you do not need to output anything from these tags 
          add an xsl:template that matches them and outputs nothing -->
     <xsl:template match="price|publish_date|description"></xsl:template>
   </xsl:stylesheet>
   ```
3. Open `book.xsl` in Firefox (it probably would also work in IE)

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to add the xsl reference to your .xml

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="myTransform.xsl"?>
```

rest of .xml follows

Otherwise you should use an xslt processor which will create your html based on your .xml and your .xsl.

Edit:

For visual studio please visit this : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302298.aspx

Comment: Thnk you for you answer, I did it but no success :(

Comment: @BabakBst Does the "myTransform.xsl" point to your .xsl file? What do you seen when you open your .xml in your browser?

Comment: in Chrome i see nothing but in IE :The system cannot locate the resource specified. Error processing resource

Comment: So your .xsl path is wrong. By the way why don't you just use a processor? Chrome is angry with local file access anyway..

Comment: Well if you .xsl is in C:\myXsl.xsl and you say something else in your .xml it won't work right? :)

Comment: i want to do that in Visual studio and both of xml and xslt file are in the same directory